# Reusing class functionality with existing class swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I worked with a tutorial to integrate the Side Menu ([here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)) into the xcode project. I have a user profile class backing up my profile view controller. I want the profile view to have the side menu, how can I do that?

the problem I am facing is that to use the side menu in the link provided I have to create a new view controller that is backed by SWRevealViewController class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an extension to UIViewController. With an extension you can add methods to ANY UIViewController subclass (or more generally to any class.)

The challenge you'll face is that extensions don't let you add instance variables. If you need state data (and an application like this probably does) you'll have to come up with a way to store it. Associative storage is an option, but that's kind of an obscure runtime feature.

Comment: hmmm I am thinking of implementing an intermediate hidden view controller...will keep trying with that until something else comes up here

Comment: "intermediate hidden view controller?" What does that mean? That sounds like an awkward, fragile solution in the making.